# Export Jupyter Notebook to HTML with VS Code & Plotly figures

Tags: python, html, jupyter, vscode-extensions, plotly-python

I'm struggling with the export of my ipynb-file to HTML via VS Code due to following requirements which I'm not able to combine:

1. The file contains plotly-figures which need to be rendered
2. The code should not be shown in the export file

My two approaches:

1. To render properly in HTML, I set

   `import plotly.io as pio`

   `pio.renderers.default='notebook'`

   exporting via VS Code "Jupyter:Export to HTML" results in showing the figures properly, but also the input.
2. To hide the code-cells in the export file I can execute

   ```
   jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input file.ipynb
   ```

   in the CLI.
   This hides the input as required, but does not render the plotly figures, since the correct renderer-option is missing (I guess).
   Adding

   `--WebPDFExporter.embed_images=True`
   did not help.

Each approach works as expected, but how to combine both?

First option would be to add an argument to VS Code Export function not to show input.

Second option would be to add an argument to cmd line that sets the correct renderer.

Any help appreciated

Comment: For me, I include `renderer='notebook'` when I call `fig.show` in the notebook. That allows me to see plotly plots in the live notebook, and `nbconvert`ed HTML. But, I guess this does the same thing as `pio.renderers.default='notebook'`, so perhaps it won't help you.

Comment: An alternative to using `--no-input` is to include a cell in the notebook that would allow you to interactively toggle code cells shown or hidden. See: https://gist.github.com/davipatti/f9e32bb575871307d42e1043e1826b98

Comment: Thanks for the input, @davipatti, putting `renderer` into fig.show() does not help. Lazy as I am I prefer setting it once and not for each figure. I tried your toggle code, but unfortunately it does not work, opening the link in a new tab shows me about:blank#blocked in the url- maybe some setting issue. Will keep that in mind either way. Cheers

Comment: You can't open the link I posted? It is public; perhaps gist.github.com is blocked for you...

Comment: I was able to access & append it to my code. It also generated the link in both, the notebook & html but in the latter nothing happened when clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.
When using CLI-approach, renderer-variable from nb *is* taken into account (no matter if set gobally via `plotly.io` or within `fig.show()`.

But notebooks needs to be saved (of course) when exported "externally" by CLI (which is not necessary when exporting directly via VS Code).
Since I'm quite new to VS Code, my assumption was that the console uses the active Kernel of the notebook which it does not.